# Split View based Ipad App : View Changed from v5.0 to v.51

Tags: ios, ipad

I m creating a Split view based application for Ipad. I have used the following code in my app to get split view in my app(http://blog.corywiles.com/creating-a-universal-ios-app-tutorial). While i was checking out, the code seems to show the result i expected in Ipad v5.0 , like a drop down list. But in Ipad v5.1 the popover view changed for the same code.

How can i get the same popover view ,which i got in v5.0 Ipad ..?

Ipad 5.0 Screenshot : http://postimage.org/image/bre31nai9/

Ipad 5.1 Screenshot : http://postimage.org/image/7waoz2rch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a change Apple introduced with the iOS 5.1 SDK. To get the old behavior, either target iOS 5.0 SDK or (preferably), use MGSplitViewController, which offers similar functionality to the old UISplitViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a way to have iOS 5.0 style popover with the split view, I just spent the last couple of hours looking and came up with a solution that puts the "over" back in "popover".  its here if you need it: [splitview poperver issues between ios5.0 and ios5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123617/splitview-poperver-issues-between-ios5-0-and-ios5-1/12126029#12126029)

be well.